# How to avoid link break or hashtag break in tweet status trimmed by LinqtoTwitter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-twitter

I am using LinqTOTwitter for retrieving user status and displaying it to our site, but when tweet size is more then 140 character, it trims the tweet. So if at end of tweet, there is a link, it will break. How can I avoid this?

For getting my tweet status from LinqTOtwitter, I am using following code.

```
List<Status> tweetstatus = 
(from stat in twitterCtx.Status 
where stat.ScreenName == ScreenName && 
stat.Type == StatusType.User && 
stat.IncludeEntities == true 
select stat).ToList();
```